# Cordova crashes when (dis)connecting bluetooth keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, bluetooth

I have an application using Android in combination with PhoneGap/Cordova 2.5.0. I have all the HTML pages and javascript files and such locally; I do not call external URL's.

It all works flawlessly, until I try to connect or disconnect a bluetooth keyboard (In my case a Kensington KeyFolio Expert). In that case, this is what happens:

1. The page reloads
2. The webview waits for like 20 seconds (I think that's the cordova default timeout?)
3. An alert with the title `Application Error` pops up, saying:

> The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};)

Or, properly indented:

```
The connection to the server was unsuccessful.    
 (javascript: try {
     cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();
 } catch (e) {
     console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');
 };)
```

I searched a little on the internet for a solution, and it was said that one should 'trick' cordova, by using the HTML below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
            window.location='./actual.html';
        </script>
    <body>      
    </body>
</html>
```

But it was to no avail. The problem persists. Other threads say that I should increase `loadUrlTimeoutValue` using `this.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);`, but also: to no avail (plus my scripts do not take more than 2 seconds to run, since it's all local).

Here's the stacktrace from what happens when I (dis)connect a bluetooth keyboard:

```
    01-21 11:53:56.216: D/DroidGap(17945): Paused the application!
    01-21 11:53:56.216: D/CordovaWebView(17945): Handle the pause
    01-21 11:53:56.257: D/DroidGap(17945): onDestroy()
    01-21 11:53:56.258: D/CordovaWebView(17945): >>> loadUrl(javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};)
    01-21 11:53:56.258: D/CordovaWebView(17945): >>> loadUrlNow()
    01-21 11:53:56.304: D/DroidGap(17945): Setting boolean properties in DroidGap will be deprecated in 3.0 on July 2013, please use config.xml
    01-21 11:53:56.305: D/DroidGap(17945): DroidGap.onCreate()
    01-21 11:53:56.310: W/art(17945): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
    01-21 11:53:56.312: W/AwContents(17945): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
    01-21 11:53:56.319: D/JsMessageQueue(17945): Set native->JS mode to 2
    01-21 11:53:56.319: W/art(17945): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
    01-21 11:53:56.320: W/art(17945): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
    01-21 11:53:56.320: D/DroidGap(17945): DroidGap.init()
    01-21 11:53:56.391: D/FileManager.getPathFromIdentifier (98)(17945): getting path from ident:, /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cordovatest/b51d8994b23e24a4b1f3211d8324a66f714ca802/1050/d0.html
    01-21 11:53:56.447: D/CordovaWebView(17945): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cordovatest/b51d8994b23e24a4b1f3211d8324a66f714ca802/1050/d0.html, 70000)
    01-21 11:53:56.447: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(splashscreen,show)
    01-21 11:53:56.447: D/CordovaWebView(17945): >>> loadUrl(file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cordovatest/b51d8994b23e24a4b1f3211d8324a66f714ca802/1050/d0.html)
    01-21 11:53:56.447: D/PluginManager(17945): init()
    01-21 11:53:56.450: D/CordovaWebView(17945): >>> loadUrlNow()
    01-21 11:53:56.469: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(onPrepareOptionsMenu,com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder@39be6cf1)
    01-21 11:53:56.476: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(onPrepareOptionsMenu,com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder@39be6cf1)
    01-21 11:53:56.477: D/DroidGap(17945): Resuming the App
    01-21 11:53:56.540: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(17945): Ignore this event
    01-21 11:53:56.607: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(17945): Ignore this event
    01-21 11:53:56.627: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(17945): Ignore this event
    01-21 11:53:56.649: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cordovatest/b51d8994b23e24a4b1f3211d8324a66f714ca802/1050/d0.html)
    01-21 11:53:56.714: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cordovatest/b51d8994b23e24a4b1f3211d8324a66f714ca802/1050/0.html)
    01-21 11:53:57.061: D/Cordova(17945): onPageFinished(file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cordovatest/b51d8994b23e24a4b1f3211d8324a66f714ca802/1050/0.html)
    01-21 11:53:57.061: D/Cordova(17945): Trying to fire onNativeReady
    01-21 11:53:57.062: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
    01-21 11:53:57.062: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.cordovatest/b51d8994b23e24a4b1f3211d8324a66f714ca802/1050/0.html)
    01-21 11:53:57.148: D/CordovaNetworkManager(17945): Connection Type: wifi
    01-21 11:53:57.151: D/CordovaNetworkManager(17945): Connection Type: wifi
    01-21 11:53:57.151: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
    01-21 11:53:57.155: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(spinner,stop)
    01-21 11:53:59.067: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(spinner,stop)
    01-21 11:54:16.290: E/CordovaWebView(17945): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
    01-21 11:54:16.290: D/Cordova(17945): CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful. URL=javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};
    01-21 11:54:16.291: D/DroidGap(17945): onMessage(onReceivedError,{"errorCode":-6,"description":"The connection to the server was unsuccessful.","url":"javascript:try{cordova.require('cordova\/channel').onDestroy.fire();}catch(e){console.log('exception firing destroy event from native');};"})
```

My question, obviously, is: why does this happen, and how can I fix this?